# Не выводит правильную высоту. JavaScript.В чем проблема ?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>  

<head>  

</head>  

<body>  

  <script language="javascript">
  var x = prompt("Enter the site fellow:  ");
  var y = prompt("Enter width: ");
  var z = prompt("Enter height: ");
  var wi = window.open(x, "fellow", "innerWidth=" + y, "innerHeight=" + z);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: достаточно посмотреть как **правильно** писать строку с параметрами  и всё станет понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следовало бы предварительно ознакомиться с документацией по [`window.open()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)...

```js
var site = prompt("Enter the site fellow:  ");
var width = prompt("Enter width: ");
var height = prompt("Enter height: ");
var wi = window.open(site, "fellow", "width=" + width + ",height=" + height);
```